# Xamarin Forms, "Invalid syntax for a hexadecimal numeric entity reference" error inside App.xaml when importing Icon

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

the font.otf is imported correctly and placed inside the correct folder because the font works on letters but importing an icon from the otf file does not work because of the  syntax error. Entering **&#x** before the icon code "uf1ea" is what caused the error but it's important for finding the icon otherwise it would just display "uf1ea" on the emulator and not the actual icon.

here's a snippet of the code i wrote in app.xaml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testingfont.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:String x:Key="Newspaper">&#xuf1ea;</x:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: have you tried encoding the ampersand as `&amp;`?

Comment: In xml, for unicode characters that are only 4 bytes, might be able to use `\xNNNN`. E.g. `...>\xf1ea<...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the icon codes in a new class, this worked for me:

```
<Label Text="&#xf1ea;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a `u` in your icon code, just use it like below:

`<x:String x:Key="Newspaper">&#xf1ea;</x:String>`

Comment: Yup, this also worked: <Label Text="&#xf1ea;"/>

Comment: Thanks for your response, Charbel!Have a great day!